# Parse simple table

Tags: perl, awk

For each line in input file, I would like to print the field that has the string 'locus_tag=', and if there is no field matching, print a dash.

Input file (tab-delimited):

```
GeneID_2=7277058    location=890211..892127 locus_tag=HAPS_0907 orientation=+
GeneID_2=7278144    gene=rlmL   location=complement(1992599..1994776)   locus_tag=HAPS_2029
GeneID_2=7278145    gene=rlmT   location=complement(1992599..1994776)   timetoparse
```

Desired output:

```
locus_tag=HAPS_0907
locus_tag=HAPS_2029
-
```

Have tried this but not working:

```
awk -F'\t' '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i ~/locus_tag=/) {print $i}; {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i !=/locus_tag=/) {print "-"}} }' SNP_annotations_ON_PROTEIN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i ~/locus_tag=/) {print $i; next} {print "-"}}' a
GeneID_2=7277058    location=890211..892127 locus_tag=HAPS_0907 orientation=+
GeneID_2=7278144    gene=rlmL   location=complement(1992599..1994776)   locus_tag=HAPS_2029
-
```

What you had:

```
{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i ~/locus_tag=/) {print $i}; {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i !=/locus_tag=/) {print "-"}} }'
```

What I wrote:

```
{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i ~/locus_tag=/) {print $i; next} {print "-"}}
                                                       ^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^
                        if found, print and go to next line        |
    if you arrive here, it is because you did not find the pattern, so print dash
```

Answer (score 6):

```
perl -lpe '($_)= (/(locus_tag=\S+)/, "-")' file
```

output

```
locus_tag=HAPS_0907
locus_tag=HAPS_2029
-
```

Comment: It's really beautiful. But I prefer readability over beauty... :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
 perl -nE 'say m/(locus_tag=\S*)/ ? $1 : q/-/'
```

Comment: `perl -M5.010 -ne` could be shortened to `perl -nE`. The `-E` option enables all optional features (such as say), though it does not enable strict.

Comment: @user49740, thanks for the tip. I haven't used `-E` yet.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/locus_tag/{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++) if($x~/^locus_tag=/) print $x;next}{print "-"}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can play with the `FS`, to make it easier:

```
awk -F'locus_tag=' 'NF>1{sub(/\s.*/,"",$2);print FS $2;next}$0="-"' f  
locus_tag=HAPS_0907
locus_tag=HAPS_2029
-
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print /(locus_tag=.*?)\s/?"$1\n":"-\n"' file
locus_tag=HAPS_0907
locus_tag=HAPS_2029
-
```

Comment: Yes, sorry... I was just optimizing the scriptlet... Now it looks like the neatest (or at least shortest :-) of the proposed answers... :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{print (match($0,/locus_tag=[^[:space:]]*/) ? substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) : "-")}' file
locus_tag=HAPS_0907
locus_tag=HAPS_2029
-
```